# Calculations with numpy roll over 3d data

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, numpy, for-loop

I have a 3d data and would like to calculate average of product of data points at all possible distances from origin. I have a huge grid (128^3-1024^3) and what I am doing now doesn't give answer in hours.

```
# u read from a file
import numpy as np
for icx in range(0,128):
    for icy in range(0,128):
        for icz in range(0,128):
            cukin[icx,icy,icz] = np.mean((u*np.roll(np.roll(np.roll(u,icx, axis=0),icy, axis=1),icz, axis=2))
```

Is there a way to avoid loops in this problem ?

Toy example:

```
cukin = np.zeros((2,2,2))
u = np.mgrid[1:5:1,1:5:1,1:5:1]
for icx in range(0,2):
    for icy in range(0,2):
        for icz in range(0,2):
            cukin[icx,icy,icz] = np.mean((u*np.roll(np.roll(np.roll(u,icx, axis=0),icy, axis=1),icz, axis=2)))
```

Gives cukin

```
[[[ 7.5   7.  ]
  [ 7.    6.5 ]]

 [[ 6.25  6.25]
  [ 6.25  6.25]]]
```

Comment: You can simplify the roll command: `np.roll(a, (i,j,k))` is valid.

Comment: @VBB that would still not avoid loops. Going through loops is time consuming part.

Comment: Make a toy version of your program with input data baked in so we can run it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck update the questions with a toy version as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try using iterators instead of lists (`range` creates a list), they consume much less memory. To iterate over all position indices at once, you can use `itertools.product`. Also roll all axis at the same time instead of calling nested `np.roll` three times:

```
from itertools import product as prod
import numpy as np

rng_x = xrange(128)
rng_y = xrange(128)
rng_z = xrange(128)
xyz_ids = prod(rng_x, rng_y, rng_z)

# NOTE: the order of the axis in numpy arrays is inverse
for i, j, k in xyz_ids:
    cukin[k, j, i] = np.mean(u * np.roll(u, [k, j, i], axis=[0, 1, 2]))
```

Not sure if will output what you expect. Let me know if it works. You should consider adding an example of what is `u` and corresponding expected output.

Comment: This still doesn't avoid loops so takes lot of time. I have updated the question with a toy example.

Comment: You can always use list comprehensions:
`cukin = np.array([np.mean(u * np.roll(u, [k, j, i], axis=[0, 1, 2])) for i, j, k in xyz_ids]).reshape(2, 2, 2)`

Comment: but i guess it still runs over 3 loops ? it is taking equally long !

Comment: Well a cube of 128 elements per axis has 2097152 elements... Anyway, it doesn't run over 3 loops, but a single (longer) iterator. Maybe you should consider changing the data type you're working on. By default, numpy works with float64 precision. Using lower size floats or integers (if possible) should speed up the calculations.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the axis in the list comprehension were wrong. This outputs the same as your toy example: `cukin = np.array([np.mean(u * np.roll(u, [k, j, i], axis=[0, 1, 2])) for k, j, i in xyz_ids]).reshape(2, 2, 2)`